# Methodology to build a Fed Funds curve post LIBOR cessation

Tags: interest-rate-swap, discount-factor-curve

With the transition from LIBOR to SOFR, what is the market standard for building a Fed Funds curve?  In the "old days", I believe that one would use Fed Funds futures for the front-end (i.e. 3-6 months or so), then use the Fed Funds / LIBOR basis swap for the longer-dated tenors.  Is there a SOFR / Fed Funds basis swap that can be used to build the Fed Funds curve?  If not, what's the best way to build the Fed Funds curve?

Note: I'm **not** referring to the OIS curve (which, by definition, is compounded).  I'm referring to a curve that can be used to price non-compounded Fed Funds swaps.

Comment: To my knowledge, Fed Funds swaps continue to trade heavily: as long as banks will participate in the overnight **unsecured** financing market (i.e. Fed Funds), there will be need to hedge this financing on a term basis. To my knowledge, SOFR (i.e. the **secured** overnight financing rate) only accommodates the financing needs of banks **partially**, with the remainder being accommodated by the **unsecured** borrowing (i.e. at the prevailing Fed Funds rate). I believe that the Fed Funds swap curve is liquid and so doesn't need to be built as a "spread", it just exists as a stand-alone curve.

Comment: PS: I would really appreciate if someone who trades the actual Fed Funds curve or builds it as a quant could answer properly, the above points are based just on my general knowledge of the subject, i.e. browsing the CME website to see their cleared products, etc. I never traded the Fed Funds curve. Hope a practitioner will provide a more thorough answer.

PPS: CME list "SOFR-Fed Funds" spread as a product, so if the spreads are more liquid than the actual Fed Funds swap of the same tenor, probably the spread would be used for the curve.

Comment: I copy Jan's comment; I have mainly seen curves that simply use liquid FedFund (compound) vs. Fixed Swaps. Re your comment on the *non* OIS Curve / compounding: could you please clarify what you mean?  I imagine that regardless of your "input" instrument, your ultimate goal in bootstrapping will probably be to produce *daily* forward rates anyways, which you can then use for whatever you like (= averaging, compounding, single-reset, lookback, etc. style coupons).

Comment: I was under the impression that the Fed Fund basis swap market (e.g. SOFR/FF and LIBOR/FF) was more liquid than the outright Fed Fund fixed swap market.  Is this the case?

Comment: Existing LIBOR/FF swaps should fall back to SOFR/FF anyway (with SOFR discounting) sooner rather than later (so fresh SOFR/FF swaps would make sense).